# Have aptitude search print full package name

Tags: aptitude, output

*Environment: aptitude called in a script.*

I'm having problems with this command:

```
aptitude search '?virtual'  |grep ^v |grep -v i386|sort|uniq
```

In particular if I do:

```
aptitude search '?virtual'  |grep ^v |grep -v i386|sort|uniq|grep adblock
```

I get (as one of the results):

```
v   adblock-plus-element-hiding-hel -
```

instead of what I want:

```
v   adblock-plus-element-hiding-helper -
```

How do I get aptitude to print the full package name in a script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `aptitude` not do do any special column formatting.

> --disable-columns
>
> This option causes **aptitude search** and **aptitude versions** to output
>   their results without any special formatting. In particular: normally
>   aptitude will add whitespace or truncate search results in an attempt
>   to fit its results into vertical “columns”. With this flag, each line
>   will be formed by replacing any format escapes in the format string
>   with the corresponding text; column widths will be ignored.

So do this instead:

```
$ aptitude search '?virtual' --disable-columns|grep ^v |grep -v i386|sort|uniq
v  a52dec - 
v  a52dec-dev - 
v  aac-tactics - 
v  aalib1 - 
v  aalib-bin - 
v  acl-dev - 
v  ada-compiler - 
v  aide-binary - 
v  alphy - 
...
```